# Need help on csv output via python

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

Okay, so I have 3 lists of data. Each one is of a different length and they have no correlation with each other.

The problem I am having is that when I go to write bList it writes to the row after where aList finished. So they're all in the proper columns, that's dandy, but I just want each column to begin on row 2 (row 1 is reserved for the headers). Instead I'm having aList start on row 1 and end on row 28, then bList starts on 29, etc.

Here is what I have and I'm hoping one of you fine wizards out there will explain how to fix it. I understand what is going on that is causing the problem, I just don't know how to fix it.

```
def write_output(file):
    f = open(file, 'w')
    fields = ('a', 'b', 'c')
    wr = csv.DictWriter(f, delimiter=",", fieldnames=fields, lineterminator = '\n')

    wr.writeheader()
    for row in aList:
        wr.writerow({'a':row})
    for row in bList:
        wr.writerow({'b':row})
    for row in cList:
        wr.writerow({'c':row})
```

Comment: You can't write a CSV element per element, you have to write it row per row.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip_longest.

Example if your lists don't contains `None` value:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

for a_b_c in zip_longest(aList, bList, cList):
    row = {k: v for k, v in zip(fields, a_b_c) if v is not None}
    wr.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for Python 3.5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully functioning example.

This script doesn't use any libraries and runs in `Python 2.7`. You can create CSV (comma-separated-values) files just by making sure every value is delimited by a comma. Also, instead of using `itertools`, I use the `map` function.

```
# Python 2.7    
# Here is an example of three lists of different lengths
aList = [9,8,2,5,14,6]
bList = [8,7,5,4]
cList = [9,15,25,60,47,88,3]

# Creates your empty CSV file
output_file = open(r'C:\Temp\output.csv', 'w')

# Adds headers in the first row
output_file.write('aList,bList,cList\n')

# Adds all the elements from the lists, row-by-row
for a, b, c in map(None, aList, bList, cList):
    output_file.write('%s,%s,%s\n' % (a, b, c))

# Closes your file
output_file.close()
```

In `Python 3`, the `map` function no longer supports `None` to be a mapping function. In this case, the `zip_longest` function from the `itertools` library is probably the cleanest approach (Note that in `Python 2.7`, this function from `itertools` is called `izip_longest`)

```
# Python 3.x
import itertools

# Here is an example of three lists of different lengths
aList = [9,8,2,5,14,6]
bList = [8,7,5,4]
cList = [9,15,25,60,47,88,3]

# Creates your empty CSV file
output_file = open(r'C:\Temp\output.csv', 'w')

# Adds headers in the first row
output_file.write('aList,bList,cList\n')

# Adds all the elements from the lists, row-by-row
for a, b, c in itertools.zip_longest(aList, bList, cList):
    output_file.write('%s,%s,%s\n' % (a, b, c))

# Closes your file
output_file.close()
```

Comment: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

That's in Python 3.5

Comment: Had to use itertools.zip_longest but I'd prefer to do it your way because no dependencies.

Comment: I prefer scripts with the least amount of external libraries as well. `itertools` is a built-in library from Python though. I edited my response with a `Python 3.x` solution.